# Encryption of keystore password in play framework

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, ssl-certificate, keystore

I am creating a keystore with the help of java key tool, and that property i have to define while starting my server in application.conf .

```
play.server.https.keyStore.path=certs/uwsca.jks
play.server.https.keyStore.type=JKS
play.server.https.keyStore.password="password"
```

But i want to store passsword as encrypted not like a normal text. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You might look for setting the conf variables while stating/building the app, try this

```
sbt -Dplay.server.https.keyStore.password=password run
```

This will override whatever you set it in conf file for that build.